# YEAR gives error

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

pgAdmin III always gives an error on year

> **ERROR:** function year(date) does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT YEAR(geboortedatum) as date_part
>   .............................^^^^.........
>
> **HINT:**  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   ********** Error **********
>
> **ERROR:** function year(date) does not exist
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Character: 8

I can get the whole date that I need but I need only the year can someone help me it needs to be the youngest year from the table.

Comment: is this MSSQL (T-SQL), MySQL, Oracle ...?

Comment: pgAdmin is probably PostgreSQL ?

Comment: @DLeh It is most likely Postgresql since OP uses pgAdmin.

Comment: okay, was asking because I couldn't tell. I added the postgresql tag for others to know.

Comment: In the time it took you to write this question I bet you could've found the answer

Comment: Postgres documentstion: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you mentioned pgAdmin, I assume that you are using Postgres, so you need write code like this (using `EXTRACT` constructure):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

[Detailed documentation for the `datetime` functions](http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.6/pg/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: lucky i knew the answer took what you wrote changed the year and bam right answer next exercise thanks